# Zsh: Is it possible to use the value of a variable as a substitution pattern?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Is it possible to do something like the following?

`g=$f:s/$in/$out/;`

or

`g=$g:s/$in[$i]/$out[$i]/;`

I've tried random character combinations like `${~in}` and `g=$g:ps/` but, as you can see, I'm not a zsh expert -- and guessing isn't getting me anywhere :-) I've even tried reading the manpages...

EDIT: I'm trying to write my own zmv-type command:

```
# in   a*b* -> a b NULL     rn a*b* *c*d   aXXbYY  -->  XXcYYd
# out  *c*d -> NULL c d     rn inv* mag*   inv.ext inv.spc -->  mag.ext mag.spc

alias rn='noglob frn'

function frn() {                                                                                                   
    local in out m n f g i
    setopt localoptions glob histsubstpattern

    in=("${(@s:*:)1}")                          # split $1 and $2 on '*'
    out=("${(@s:*:)2}")                         # keeping NULL fields

    m=${#in[@]}                                 # count n(array-elements)
    n=${#out[@]}

    if [[ $m = $n ]] {
        foreach f ($~1)                         # foreach file in globbed $1
            g=$f
            for (( i = 1; i < n; i += 1 )); do
                g=$g:s/$in[$i]/$out[$i]/        # subst corresponding fields
            done

            g=$g:s/%$in[$i]/$out[$i]/           # last subst has % anchor

            print '$f --> $g'
            mv $f $g
        end
    } else {
        print "n(*) must be same for both patterns"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement [`zmv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) `-W`?

Comment: Apparently :-). I've only just started with zsh (and shell scripting, at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `$out` which is expanded, `$in` is treated as a literal string here... so nothing happens (unless `f` contained `$in` literally).
To expand in the left-hand side you'd need [`HIST_SUBST_PATTERN` set](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers):

> `s/l/r[/]`
>
> Substitute `r` for `l` as described below.
> ...........
> By default the left-hand side of substitutions are not patterns, but
> character strings[...]
> ...........
> If the option `HIST_SUBST_PATTERN`
> is set, `l` is treated as a pattern of the usual form described in
> Filename Generation.

So

```
setopt histsubstpattern
```

and then it should work...

Comment: You're correct that the 'r' pattern in $out works. But for the 'l' pattern, HIST_SUBST_PATTERN seems to let you type s/*neg/pos/  and have '*neg' interpreted as a regex, rather than the string '\\*neg'. It doesn't seem to help with reading the variable's contents.

Comment: @colinh - not sure what you mean by that...  If I run  `f=john; in=n; out=x; g=$f:s/$in/$out/; echo $g` it prints `johx` . Isn't that the expected result?

Comment: Huh. You're right. I've probably got a typo somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to try and reimplement `zmv -W` is very brittle.

In `rfn a*b*c b*c*d` applied to `acrobatic` which it should change to `bcrocatid`, you'd attempting to do

- a -> b
- b -> c
- c -> d

in succession, but that would yield:

- acrobatic -> bcrobatic
- bcrobatic -> ccrobatic
- ccrobatic -> dcrobatic

Just do it the same way `zmv -W` does by

1. Changing the `a*b*c` pattern to `(#b)a(*)b(*)c` to enable back-references
2. Changing the `b*c*d` replacement to `b$match[1]c$match[2]d`
3. And perform one substitution with either the Korn-style `${var/pattern/replacement}` or csh-stype `$var:s/pattern/replacement` with `histsubstpattern` or with zsh 6.0+ with the [`:S` modifier](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00545.html) which uses patterns with or without `histsubstpattern`.

```
function frn {
  emulate -L zsh
  set -o extendedglob
  local glob=$1 replacement=$2 n=0 file newfile

  pattern=${glob//'*'/'(*)'}
  replacement=${replacement//(#m)'*'/\$match[$((++n))]}

  for file ($~glob) {
    newfile=${file/#%(#b)$~pattern/${(Xe)replacement}}
    if [[ -n $newfile && $file != $newfile ]] {
      print -ru2 -- "${(q+)file} -> ${(q+)newfile}"
      # mv -- $file $newfile
    }
  }
}
alias frn='noglob frn'
```

Then:

```
$ frn a*b*c b*c*d
acrobatic -> bcrocatid
```

Same as:

```
$ alias zmvw='noglob zmv -W'
$ zmvw -n a*b*c b*c*d
mv -- acrobatic bcrocatid
```

Except `zmv` handles more wildcards than just `*` and does a lot more sanity checks and error handling.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Unfortunately one can't accept multiple answers.

Comment: @colinh - you can always un-accept an answer and accept another one, it's _perfectly fine_. At the time of my posting your question was quite  succinct and didn't explain your actual goal. As it stands now, Stéphane's post answers your question better than mine.

Comment: @don - true, but yours answers the actual question (posed in the title). :-) I added the goal in case it was an XY problem.